# Extract data from an array of Object

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this array of Object that I am getting from my database:

[Array of Object][1]

I would like to make an array of array for each value, but I can't manage to find a way to do it as I'm a beginner of javascript.

For example :

```
var Stats=[
  [39,49,43,42,41,35], //SGW Value for each Object
  [37,44,49,46,52,42], //UD Value for each Object 
  [8,11,8,8,16,15],    //Virtual Value for each Object
  ...     
]
```

The goal is to make a chart on chart.js that look like that :

[Chart Goal][2]

I would need to loop the dataset because I'll add more data and it would be way too long to set each dataset individually.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's not array of objects.. it's a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: better is can you show an example of how do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create an array for each property you want to plot; i.e.:

```
var fsp = [],
    msg = [],
    sgw = [];
```

Then you can loop over your dataset and put the data in each array:

```
yourArray.forEach(function(obj){
    //obj takes the value of each object in the database
    fsp.push(obj.fsp);
    msg.push(obj.msg);
    sgw.push(obj.sgw);
})
```

or, if you are more familiar with `for` loop

```
for(var obj of yourArray){
    fsp.push(obj.fsp);
    msg.push(obj.msg);
    sgw.push(obj.sgw);
}
```

Finally you can create an array as you pointed in your example

```
var result = [];

result.push(fsp, msg, sgw);
```

And the result will be

```
[
    [89, 59, 43, 60, 81, 34, 28, 58, 75, 41],
    [77, 91, 4, 56, 6, 1, 42, 82, 97, 18],
    [24, 34, 4, 13, 75, 34, 14, 41, 20, 38]
]
```

For more informations take a look at [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) documentations

### **EDIT**

As you pointed in your comment, you can generate arrays dynamically creating an object like `var arrays = {};`. Then in `forEach()`, or if `for...of`, you need to loop over objects with a `for...in` loop. The variable you declare in loop's head takes the value of index, numeric for Arrays, literal for Objects. You have to do something like:

```
yourArray.forEach(function(obj){
    for(let index in obj){
        if(!arrays[index]) // check if property has already been set and initialized
            arrays[index] = []; // if not, it's initialized

        arrays[index].push(obj[index]) // push the value into the array
    }
})
```

Note that Object has been treated as Array because you access its properties with a variable filled at runtime.

The result will be:

```
arrays = {
    fsp: [89, 59, 43, 60, 81, 34, 28, 58, 75, 41],
    msg: [77, 91, 4, 56, 6, 1, 42, 82, 97, 18],
    sgw: [24, 34, 4, 13, 75, 34, 14, 41, 20, 38]
}
```

To obtain only arrays use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

If you cannot imagine how this works, I suggest you to make some examples in Chrome Developer Tools' console, or in Node's console, or wherever you can have a realtime feedback, putting in the middle of code some `console.log()` of variables

Comment: Thank you for tour answer. Yes I already done that, but on a smaller graph, for a bigger graph it would be useful to create each array in a loop and then directly add data.

Comment: @Amoos51 Edited my answer to include what you asked in question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    param1: 10,
    param2: 20
  },
  {
    param1: 30,
    param2: 40
  }
]

let array2 = array1.map(item => Object.values(item));

console.log(array2); // prints [[10, 20], [30, 40]]
```

Comment: That's not the answer to this exact question, but that's what I was looking for! Thanks!